# Why SendKeys.SendWait not working to excel file that located in shared drive?

Tags: c#, excel, wpf

I create a program which open and template excel file populate data from OLEB and I need to send a "F2" to a cell for the data to execute "line break" before saving it with specific name

Example:

In a cell before F2:

```
 JOB 0001000            LogoZeroProduct
```

After F2 is send :

```
 JOB 0001000             
 LogoZeroProduct
```

I share this template along the network drive so other people can access it.
when I test my program at first it working, but it not working when I used with other computer.

Do you know the reason or any suggestion to resolve it?

Thank for answering

Comment: Do you load the Excel then have the system send F2? If so do you do a Thread.Sleep() or something for a period of time? If so it could be a timing issue. More information on this whole process would help.

Comment: @Kelly Yes, I do. Hmm, yes, my program did not do any Thread.Sleep(), however I do have a Dispatcher going on, maybe that the reason. I will check on the timing. Thanks